URL encoding bug results in broken blog link in the Community Bulletin
This link redirects to a "Page not found" page.

Here's the link.
https://stackoverflow.blog/undefined/kohsuke-kawaguchi-jenkins-ci-cd-cloudbees/?cb=1
Result


Hmm, so the link in the sidebar returns a 302 redirecting to that link with the "undefined". Playing around with some of the links that actually work I can reproduce the error by changing the slug to be invalid / different. So possibly they changed the title / slug of the blog post but that hasn't reflected to the sidebar.

I am amused because my only experience with Jenkins is fixing a bug resulting from their absolutely crazy handling of environment variables, requiring dumb encoding shenanigans, and here we have Jenkins with an encoding bug.

This is status-completed now, the sidebar doesn't have the extraneous slash anymore and the link there works.

Missing URL Encoding strikes Stack Overflow once again, there is an extra / in the URL which must be escaped (or shouldn't be there to begin with).
The link in the sidebar is:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/09/06//kohsuke-kawaguchi-jenkins-ci-cd-cloudbees/?cb=1
                                      ^

when  it should be
https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/09/06/%2Fkohsuke-kawaguchi-jenkins-ci-cd-cloudbees/?cb=1

which worked.

I guess the post was renamed, because your link no longer works, it's now at https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/09/06/kohsuke-kawaguchi-jenkins-ci-cd-cloudbees/
